# What is the right way to safely remove external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disconnect

I have an external HDD which was pulled out from an old laptop and wrapped up with plastic cover. I can connect that same HDD with USB cable to my new PC. My question here is, can i just eject that external HDD and unplug it from USB, or do I have to turn off my PC completely in order to make my disk shut itself down and then disconnect it from USB?

This is actually real magnetic hard disc, not SSD or flash memory, just to be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Most external HDD are nothing more than an internal HDD in a case with a SATA-to-USB adapter. So no need to turn off your computer, you can use your disk like any regular external HDD. To remove it safely you can use your file manager's eject option or the `umount` command-line tool.

Answer (score 1):

I eject, then unplug any usb HDD without any problem.
Problem could appear if unplugging  before the end of writing on the disk → eject first.